# Android. Ошибка: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mate.files/mate.files.Welcome}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #67

Tags: android, activity, runtime

...  Binary XML file line #67: Error inflating class Spinner

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/welcome_screen"
     tools:context=".Welcome">
 
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/WelcomeTitle"
         android:layout_width="372dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
         android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
         android:text="@string/WelcomeTitle"
         android:textAlignment="center"
         android:textColor="@color/TextDarkTheme"
         android:textSize="@dimen/TitleText"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.125"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
 
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
 
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/WelcomeMsg"
         android:layout_width="371dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
         android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
         android:hyphenationFrequency="full"
         android:text="@string/WelcomeMsg"
         android:textAlignment="textStart"
         android:textColor="@color/TextDarkTheme"
         android:textSize="@dimen/GeneralText"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.45"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/WelcomeTitle" />
 
     <Button
         android:id="@+id/nextButton"
         style="@style/ButtonTheme"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginStart="112dp"
         android:layout_marginEnd="112dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
         android:background="@color/ButtonDefault"
         android:backgroundTint="@color/ButtonDefault"
         android:backgroundTintMode="add"
         android:longClickable="false"
         android:onClick="GetStartedClicked"
         android:text="@string/LetsGetStarted"
         android:textAllCaps="false"
         android:textColor="@color/TextDarkTheme"
         android:textSize="@dimen/GeneralText"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         app:shapeAppearance="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Material3.Button" />
 
     <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/Lang"
         android:layout_width="409dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
         android:entries="@array/Langs"
         android:onClick="LangClicked"
         android:spinnerMode="dialog"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: У вас ошибка в xml файле. зачем вы нам код приводите?

Comment: Да, тупанул. Только где тут на 67 строке ошибка?

Comment: А какая строка у вас 67?

Comment: <Spinner А если уберу лишний текст сверху, то android:layout_width="409dp"

Comment: А вы спинер в gradle подключили? Не помню, нужно или нет это

Comment: Эм... А как? Сорри если я тупой.

Comment: Между textview что за левая строчка?

Comment: Вот тут ошибка. Нет у тебя такой функции. `android:onClick="LangClicked"`

Comment: Вообще-то есть: public void LangClicked(View view)
     {
        Counter = 1;
     }   В Welcome.java

Answer (score 0):

Удалите `android:onClick="LangClicked"` и назначьте обработчик нажатий так

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //........

        Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.Lang);
        spinner.setOnTouchListener(spinnerOnTouch);
        spinner.setOnKeyListener(spinnerOnKey);
    }

    private View.OnTouchListener spinnerOnTouch = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                //сюда код
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    private static View.OnKeyListener spinnerOnKey = new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
                //сюда код
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
}
```